# Remove All White Space Between Tags

Tags: formatting, pdftex

I couldn't find a question that answers this. I'm new to tex so I'm trying to figure out how the spacing works. Basically I want the following to to appear as if it's one word with different highlighting:

My preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} % din a4, 11 pt, one sided
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\setlength{\parskip}{0in}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{orange}{HTML}{FF9456}
\definecolor{red}{HTML}{DD7A7A}
\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{93B5EA}

\newcommand{\orahi}[1]{\colorbox{orange}{#1}}
\newcommand{\redhi}[1]{\colorbox{red}{#1}}
\newcommand{\bluhi}[1]{\colorbox{blue}{#1}}
```

My text:

```
\orahi{sometexthere}
\redhi{sometexthere}
\bluhi{bluetexthere}
```

The output (PDF):

[image: initial tex output]

Removing the carriage returns between tags helps the actual white space, but not padding between words:

```
\orahi{sometexthere}\redhi{sometexthere}\bluhi{bluetexthere}
```

[image]

Again I want this to just appear as if it is one word with different highlight colors. Ideally it would be across many lines as shown in the first example, because this will eventually be a long string generated by Jinja. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Likely the more powerfull``tcolorbox`` could help to control the (unwanted) padding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to comment out (or not add) the linebreaks which are inter-word spaces, and `\colorbox` adds padding of `\fboxsep` around its content so you can add

```
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
\orahi{sometexthere}%
\redhi{sometexthere}%
\bluhi{bluetexthere}%
```